# How to determine the bounding curve of a moving circular sector?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, problem-solving, curves

**Preamble:** Consider the curve $\mathcal{C}$ formed by the segments $CD$, $DE$, $EB$ and the arc $BC$ presented below: [image: here]

Next, let $F$ be a "perspective" point and $l$ a line segment whose other end point is $A$. Suppose that we draw similar curves for each point $T$on the line segment $l$, such that the bottom segment $DE$ in the picture is orthogonal to the ray originating from $F$ and passing through $T$. Below is my best attempt to graph that this looks like at the end points of a segment from $(0, 0)$ to $(2, 0)$. (N.B., the distances are not exact in the picture, as I don't know how to use GeoGebra well).[image]

**Question:** I would like to determine the bounding curve for the shape which is obtained by the moving/painting area. That is, what is the minimal curve $\mathcal{M}$ which contains all of the "moving" curves $\mathcal{C}$?

It is quite clear that portion of the bounding curve are given by the segments $CD$, $DA$ of the leftmost area, and by the segments $AE$, $EB$ of the righmost area. What I'm struggling with is how to determine the bounding shape of the moving arc given that the line $l$ (the line segment which curve $\mathcal{C}$ moves along) and the perspective point $F$ can be be arbitary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point of vocabulary: The generic name of this kind of "bounding curve" is "envelope".

This is not a full answer: it gives, under the parametric representation (1) the biggest part of the equation of the upper envelope.

Take a look at the following picture (obtained with Desmos: you can see an animated version [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aebxf5jd4z).

[image]

The locus of $C$ is the red curve, the locus of $D$ is the purple curve.

The parameters are

- the radius $r$ of the circular arc,
- the aperture angle $2a$ of this arc,
- the ordinate $b$ of point $F$.

The locus of point $C$ is given under the form of parametric equations that can be seen on the upper left of the figure:

$$\begin{cases}x&=&r\cdot\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{-b}{t}\right)+a\right)+t\\y&=&r\cdot\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{-b}{t}\right)+a\right)\end{cases} \ \text{where} \ t \ \text{is the abscissa or the arc's center}\tag{1}$$

For point $D$ change $a$ into $-a$.

**Explanation** about the angles found in (1): let $N$ be the midpoint of arc $LM$. As points $F,G,N$ are aligned, if we denote by $t$ the abscissa of $G$:

$$\text{angle of GN w.r.t.} \ x \ \text{axis} \ = \ \angle AGF = \arctan \frac{AF}{AG}=\arctan \frac{-b}{t}$$

To this angle, we add (resp. subtract) angle $a$ in order to obtain point $M$ (resp. point $L$).

The animation shows that, in the first quadrant, it is essentially this point $C$ that governs the "envelope", with an exception around the origin (in the animation here it is the case for $x<0.5$).

This disruption, calling a specific analysis, slightly increases when $a$ becomes important (say $>\pi/4$). The analysis of this exceptional zone looks possible but more complicated...

Waiting for your reactions.

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: I just added an explanation about angles...

Comment: Looks great! I suppose that the general case just requires more detailed analysis in the same fashion. What I'm currently struggling with is how to use as few parameters as possible to parametrize the arc portion of the envelope when the segment with which we move can be aligned arbitrarily w.r.t. to an arbitrary perspective point.