# Finding an envelope for a moving circular sector

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, interpolation, parametrization, envelope

**Preamble:** I want to find the curve which bounds a moving circular sector, i.e. an envelope for the following family of plane curves. Suppose that we are given a "perspective" point $T$ and start and end points of a line segment. Define $C(p, \alpha, s)$ as the circular sector which is drawn in the following way: Pick a point from the line segment between $S$ and $E$ and call it $p$. Draw a ray $R$ originating from $T$, which passes through $p$. Pick a point $p_0$ at distance $s$ from $p$ along $R$. Two other points from the arc of the circular sector are given by first rotating $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ radians from $R$ and then advancing by $s$ units. Call these points $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively. Now one can draw the arc of the sector with $p_1, p_2, p$.

As $p$ moves from $S$ to $E$, the arc of the circular sector rotates.  Here is an illustration of the setting: [Moving sector](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q9psjsa2fj) where 1.) T is the perspective point, 2.) S and E are the start and end points of the line segment, 3.) $2\alpha$ is the angle of the sector and $s$ is its radius (calling it anything other than $r$ was easier due to Desmos wanting to plot a unit circle with $r$), 4.) $O$ is the parametrized center of the sector along the line segment from $S$ to $E$, 5.) $u$ is the parameter value, 6.) arcs $G$ and $H$ are paths drawn by end points of the sector during its movement, 7.) $k_2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial u} k$ derivative of the angle $k$ w.r.t. the parameter $u$ (for some reason Desmos did not like me using $\theta$, so I had to resort to $k$), 8.) $P_3 = \frac{\partial}{\partial u}O$ is derivative of the center of the circular sector $O$ w.r.t. $u$.

This post also contains more discussion of this problem: [How to determine the bounding curve of a moving circular sector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317766/how-to-determine-the-bounding-curve-of-a-moving-circular-sector)

**Question:** What is currently unclear to me is that does the said family of moving circular sectors have an envelope? If it does, how should/could I solve either its implicit equation for $x$ and $y$ or some parametrized version of it? IMO currently, the sources of trouble are those parts of my equations, which have the parameter value $u$ inside sine, cosine and arctan. To put it bluntly, I have no clue how to eliminate $u$ from the system of equations $\begin{cases}C(p(u), \alpha, s) &= 0\\\frac{\partial}{\partial u}C(p(u), \alpha, s) &= 0\end{cases}$. One approach, which I have not yet tried, is parametrizing the arc with stereographic projection and using Taylor/Padre expansion for arctan.

Alternatively, if you happen to know some good interpolation method, I would be happy to hear about **if** the interpolated curve is never "smaller" than the true bounding curve. In the example [Moving sector](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q9psjsa2fj), due to my initial set up (not present in the demo) I first thought that I could just track the movement of the outermost points of the arc of the sector (arcs $G$ and $H$). However, you can clearly see that for parameter value(s) $u \approx 0.333$, $G$ and $H$ do not bound the arc of the sector.

Comment: How did you come across this question?

Comment: @Christian I encountered a bit more complicated version of this problem during the last summer as a trainee. My solution was based on brute force, and now when I have more time to think I am curious if anyone happens to know a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hspace{3cm}$ [image]

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a straight line you can always rotate and stretch your coordinate system such that $T$ is at $(0,-1)$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is the $x$-axis. If the center of the arc is at $(k,0)$ and its radius is $r$ the location of $P_1$ and $P_2$ is

$$x = k - r \cos \big( \arctan (k) \pm \alpha\big), \quad y = r \sin \big( \arctan (k) \pm \alpha \big)$$

Solving the second equation for $k$ and substituting that into the first equation yields

$$x = \tan \left( \pm \alpha - \arccos \left(\frac y r \right) \right) - \sqrt{r^2 - y^2}$$

where both branches complement each other beacause of the symmetry.

Additionally, if $|k| < \tan(\alpha)$ the arc reaches higher than its endpoints (also, for $\alpha > \frac \pi 2$ the endpoints never reach the top).

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a path of line segments you may have to add a small portion of the arc to the envelope at the connection points of the segments.

You can find the interactive plot [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9fvr3gltl7).

Comment: Thank you! While the slightly more general case of multiple line segments and boundary of the sector (e.g. segments connecting the center and endpoints of the arc) will require additional work, I see this definitely as a step in the right direction!